# Layout not overing FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to display android:id="@+id/menu_layout" fullscreen over layout that contains FragmentContainerView and BottomNavbar  blocking it with somehow. The part of over toolbar works.
I want to achive full screen android:id="@+id/menu_layout" 
If I make FragmentContainerView  android:layout_height="0dp" it displays the layout
Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/catchupColor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/header_logo"/>



    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_on_demand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/catchupColor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLogoText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_down_white_24x24"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3.6sp"
            android:text="On Demand"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_list"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icn_search"
            android:visibility="visible" />






    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#BE000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_img_close"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/main_menu_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mysat_nav">


        </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#020712"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the elevation of `menu_layout` something like

`android:elevation="10dp"`